# Extending Arrays of Arrays - Swift 4.1

Tags: arrays, swift, where-clause, extension-methods

## Extend Arrays of Arrays

#### Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3

How do I extend `Array<Array>` in Swift?

```swift
extension Array where Element == Array { //This is where the error occurs
    someMethod()
}
```

Furthermore, how would I extend an array of arrays of a specific type, for example:

```swift
extension Array where Element == Array<Int> { //Can I even do this?
    someOtherMethod()
}
```

---

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you can use generic  `func filterWithId<T where T : Idable>() -> [T] {   }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend in either way

```
extension Array where Element == Int {

    func someIntegers() {

    }
}

extension Array where Element == Array<String> {

    func someStrings() {

    }
}
```

and call like this anywhere,

```
[0, 1, 2].someIntegers()

[["hi"]].someStrings()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used

```
extension Array where Element: RandomAccessCollection, Element.Index == Int {
}
```

e.g. to add custom subscripts by `IndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for someone wanting to do this more generically than the answers so far have shown.

Extending `Array<Array>`:

```
protocol ExpressibleAsDouble { // for illustration
    func asDouble() -> Double
}

extension Array where Element: Sequence, Element.Element: ExpressibleAsDouble {
    func asDoubles() -> [[Double]] {
        return self.map { row in
            row.map { scalar in
                scalar.asDouble()
            }
        }
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------
//example usage
extension Int: ExpressibleAsDouble {
    func asDouble() -> Double {
        return Double(self)
    }
}

let ints: [[Int]] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print(ints.asDoubles())
// prints: [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```

This is actually extending `Array<any sequence, Array being one possible option>`, I'm not sure if you can constrict it to just `Array<Array>` if you want to refer to the nested scalars generically.

`Element` refers to the first dimension of the `Array` (which is another Array), and `Element.Element` refers to the type of the nested dimension (which are scalars if we're talking about a 2D array).

Answer (score 0):

Solution for generic approach (Swift 5.5):

```
extension Collection where Element: Collection, Element.Element: Equatable, Element.Index == Int {

    // Returns aggregated count of all elements.
    func totalCount() -> Int {
        return reduce(into: 0) { partialResult, innerCollection in
            partialResult += innerCollection.count
        }
    }

    // Returns `IndexPath` for given `element` inside 2d array.
    func indexPath(for element: Element.Element) -> IndexPath? {
        for (section, innerCollection) in enumerated() {
            if let row = innerCollection.firstIndex(of: element) {
                return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```